# Basic JavaScript variable definition

Tags: javascript

Coming from Python, learning JavaScript:

```
var test = 1;
var test2 = function(arg) {console.log(arg);};
```

When I execute `var test3 = test2(test);` in console, I get as a response:

```
undefined
1
```

But when I re-enter `test3` or `console.log(test3)` I'm getting the `undefined` response inestead of `1`. I tried to return value in function instead:

```
var test2 = function(arg) {return(console.log(arg));};
```

and

```
var test2 = function(arg) { var text = console.log(arg); return text;};
```

But I'm still getting the same response. How to 'bind' result of the function `test2` to variable `test3`?

Thanks.

Comment: You're actually getting the result, but the default return value for any function in javascript is `undefined`, and that goes for `console.log()` as well.

Comment: Because the function does not have a value. To add one use `return`. For example: `function(arg) {console.log(arg); return arg;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log` returns `undefined`.

```
var test2 = function(arg) { 
    var text = console.log(arg); // text === undefined
    return text;
}; // returns undefined

// Then ...

var test3 = test2(test); // test3 === undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` always returns `undefined`

If you did `return arg` instead of returning what `console.log` returns, then you'd be good.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting test3 to anything. `Console.log` does not return anything(except undefined).

If you want to set it to the value of arg, just return the value itself.